# Comparison of Discrete Cosine Transform and Discrete Wavelet Transform

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis, wavelet-analysis

I would like to compare the sorted coefficients of the Discrete Cosine Transform with that of the Discrete Wavelet Transform using the Haar wavelets. From theory, the discrete wavelet transform offers more compaction of the coefficient energy into lower frequencies than the DCT. However in Mathematica I am getting the opposite result. Here is the image I am compressing:

[image]

here is the code

[image]
[image]

```
TruckData = ImageData[GTruck];
partdata = Partition[TruckData, {8, 8}, {8, 8}, 1, 0];
t = Map[FourierDCT[#, 2] &, partdata];
coeffs = Sort[Flatten[t], Greater];

wtdata = DiscreteWaveletTransform[GTruck];
wcoeffs = Sort[Flatten[wtdata[Automatic, "Values"]], Greater];

ListLogPlot[{coeffs[[1 ;; 4000]], wcoeffs[[1 ;; 4000]]}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

As can be seen, the top curve which corresponds to the DWT is of higher magnitude. The situation should be reversed.

Why is that?